# Deploy Security Domain on Jboss

Tags: jboss, jaas

Is there a possibility to make my application setup the security domain? 
Basically I need setup my application for JAAS but when I deploy it.
The target server is a JBoss 7.

Comment: This does not make sense. Why would you want to tie the security domain to your application? It should be the other way around. You define security domains and then the apps utilize the domain as per auth/authz requirements.

Comment: I want that my app write the securtiy domain config on my standalone.xml. Today I've got a app without jaas... and now I have to use it, but, I don't want edit each server of my customers(-+100).

Comment: So if you are provisioning JBoss yourself then you should use the [DMR API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/The+native+management+API) and configure & provision it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the [JBoss DRM Library](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Detyped+management+and+the+jboss-dmr+library)